# How to get a parameter value of data using ajax form from JSP to servlet using POST

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I needed to pass a  variable value from JSP to servlet, my JSP and servlet is as given below :

JSP snippet :

```
var state = $("#state").val();
        console.log("state name in submitAddForm()"+state)
    if (confirm("You have requested to add account.Do you want to continue?")) {
            $('#targetAccountsForAddAccountsForm').ajaxForm({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/account/uploadAddAccounts.action",
                data:{"state":state},
                dataType: "text",
                success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
                },
                error :function(){
                    alert("Uploading the file failed.");
                }
            });
```

Servlet Code :

```
@RequestMapping("/account/uploadAddAccounts")
    @ResponseBody
    public String uploadAddAccounts(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
        
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
```

--> the state value comes null in the servlet here , I have tried passing with single and double quotes as well as jQuery.param({ state: state}) , none of them works.

Comment: Hi, did you check if `$("#state").val()` actually have any value ?

Comment: Yes that has a value..

Comment: Open your network tab -> XHR (there you will see details about your ajax call see if values are getting pass or not)